# Fabric.js / canvas infinite background grid like miro

Tags: javascript, canvas, grid, fabricjs

Cheers community,

finally, I got my first question here on StackOverflow and it's all about "infinite grid" with fabric.js - if you have any feedback on my question pls hit me up!

**The Project:**
I try to develop a little drawing tool with [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) and wondering how I can implement an infinite background grid like miro has.

[image]

**My requirements or personal goals to this project/question**:

1. Zooming in and out - resize the grid like miro
2. Panning also affects the background grid like miro
3. Dynamic Canvas size -> if I resize the browser, the grid is also fitted canvas with /height

Found a lot of useful links but without zooming, panning, resizing or with a bad performance. If you have any "best practice" hints, links or ideas pls share with me :-)

Thx for your time and help!

Comment: Have you found any good solution ?

Comment: @Umanda actually not, our client rejected this feature

Comment: I am doing a couple of RnDs, but seems like if I add a grid ( lines ) inside the canvas, it will significantly effecting to the canvas, and it is very difficult to handle other objects.  I am thinking about how this can be done, your thoughts most welcome :)

This is some this I am trying

https://codepen.io/umanda/pen/YzEbrLx

Comment: any updates on this? Found any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution related to the creation of a separate class, which is added first to the canvas, so that everything is drawn on top of the grid.

**Here is the code:**

```
const GRID_COLOR = "#000000";
const GRID_OPACITY = 0.3;
const CELL_SIZE = 20;

const MAX_SCALE = 2;
const MIN_SCALE = 0.5;

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas', {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,165,0)',
    selectionColor: 'rgba(100,100,100,0.3)', // selection with opacity 0.3
    selectionLineWidth: 2,
    width: window.outerWidth,
    height: window.outerHeight,
    viewportTransform: [1, 0, 0, 1, -window.outerWidth/2, -window.outerHeight/2],
    //stopContextMenu: true, // prevent the right-click context menu from appearing
    fireRightClick: true, // enable firing of right click events
    fireMiddleClick: true, // enable firing of middle click events
});
window.onresize = function() {
    canvas.setWidth(window.outerWidth);
    canvas.setHeight(window.outerHeight);
};

canvas.on("mouse:wheel", function(opt) {
    let zoom = canvas.getZoom();
    zoom *= 0.999 ** opt.e.deltaY;
    if (zoom > MAX_SCALE) zoom = MAX_SCALE;
    if (zoom < MIN_SCALE) zoom = MIN_SCALE;
    
    canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: opt.e.offsetX, y: opt.e.offsetY }, zoom);
    opt.e.preventDefault();
    opt.e.stopPropagation();

});

canvas.on("mouse:up", function(opt) {
    this.setViewportTransform(this.viewportTransform);
    this.isDragging = false;
    this.selection = true;
});

canvas.on("mouse:down", function(opt) {
    if (opt.e.button === 1) {
        this.isDragging = true;
        this.selection = false;
        this.lastPosX = opt.e.clientX;
        this.lastPosY = opt.e.clientY;
    }
});

canvas.on("mouse:move", function(opt) {
    if (this.isDragging) {
        this.viewportTransform[4] += opt.e.clientX - this.lastPosX;
        this.viewportTransform[5] += opt.e.clientY - this.lastPosY;
        
        this.lastPosX = opt.e.clientX;
        this.lastPosY = opt.e.clientY;
        this.requestRenderAll();
    }
});

var infBGrid = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Object, {
    type: 'infBGrid',
    
    initialize: function () {
        
    },
    
    render: function (ctx) {
        let zoom = canvas.getZoom();
        let offX = canvas.viewportTransform[4];
        let offY = canvas.viewportTransform[5];

        ctx.save();
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#cecece";
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;

        let gridSize = CELL_SIZE * zoom;

        const numCellsX = Math.ceil(canvas.width / gridSize);
        const numCellsY = Math.ceil(canvas.height / gridSize);

        let gridOffsetX = offX % gridSize;
        let gridOffsetY = offY % gridSize;
        ctx.beginPath();
        // draw vectical lines
        for (let i = 0; i <= numCellsX; i++) {
          let x = gridOffsetX + i * gridSize;
          ctx.moveTo((x - offX) / zoom, (0 - offY) / zoom);
          ctx.lineTo((x - offX) / zoom, (canvas.height - offY) / zoom);
          }
      
        // draw horizontal lines
        for (let i = 0; i <= numCellsY; i++) {
          let y = gridOffsetY + i * gridSize;
          ctx.moveTo((0 - offX) / zoom, (y - offY) / zoom);
          ctx.lineTo((canvas.width - offX) / zoom, (y - offY) / zoom);
        }
      
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();
    }
});

var bg = new infBGrid();

canvas.add(bg);
canvas.renderAll();
```

I guess creating a class and writing code in the render method is better than creating a group that you will have to move when moving the vieport.

**A bad solution, but a workable one too:**

```
const GRID_COLOR = "#000000";
const GRID_OPACITY = 0.3;
const CELL_SIZE = 20;

const MAX_SCALE = 2;
const MIN_SCALE = 0.5;

let grid_size = CELL_SIZE / MIN_SCALE;

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas', {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,165,0)',
    selectionColor: 'rgba(100,100,100,0.3)', // selection with opacity 0.3
    selectionLineWidth: 2,
    width: window.outerWidth,
    height: window.outerHeight,
    viewportTransform: [1, 0, 0, 1, -window.outerWidth/2, -window.outerHeight/2],
    //stopContextMenu: true, // prevent the right-click context menu from appearing
    fireRightClick: true, // enable firing of right click events
    fireMiddleClick: true, // enable firing of middle click events
});
window.onresize = function() {
    canvas.setWidth(window.outerWidth);
    canvas.setHeight(window.outerHeight);
};

function snapToGrid(point) {
    return Math.round(point / grid_size) * grid_size;
}

let backgroundGrid = new fabric.Group([]);
backgroundGrid.excludeFromExport = true; // when true, object is not exported in OBJECT/JSON
backgroundGrid.hasControls = false;
backgroundGrid.hasBorders = false;
backgroundGrid.evented = false;
backgroundGrid.selectable = false;

canvas.on("mouse:wheel", function(opt) {
    let zoom = canvas.getZoom();
    zoom *= 0.999 ** opt.e.deltaY;
    if (zoom > MAX_SCALE) zoom = MAX_SCALE;
    if (zoom < MIN_SCALE) zoom = MIN_SCALE;
    
    canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: opt.e.offsetX, y: opt.e.offsetY }, zoom);
    opt.e.preventDefault();
    opt.e.stopPropagation();

    backgroundGrid.setPositionByOrigin(
        new fabric.Point (
            snapToGrid(-canvas.viewportTransform[4] / canvas.getZoom()),
            snapToGrid(-canvas.viewportTransform[5] / canvas.getZoom())
        ), 
        "left", "top"
    );
});

canvas.on("mouse:down", function(opt) {
    if (opt.e.button === 1) {
        this.isDragging = true;
        this.selection = false;
        this.lastPosX = opt.e.clientX;
        this.lastPosY = opt.e.clientY;
    }
});

canvas.on("mouse:up", function(opt) {
    this.setViewportTransform(this.viewportTransform);
    this.isDragging = false;
    this.selection = true;
});

canvas.on("mouse:move", function(opt) {
    if (this.isDragging) {
        this.viewportTransform[4] += opt.e.clientX - this.lastPosX;
        this.viewportTransform[5] += opt.e.clientY - this.lastPosY;
        
        backgroundGrid.setPositionByOrigin(
            new fabric.Point (
                snapToGrid(-canvas.viewportTransform[4] / canvas.getZoom()),
                snapToGrid(-canvas.viewportTransform[5] / canvas.getZoom())
            ), 
            "left", "top"
        );

        this.requestRenderAll();
        this.lastPosX = opt.e.clientX;
        this.lastPosY = opt.e.clientY;
    }
});
function bgGrid() {
    const numCellsX = Math.ceil(canvas.width / MIN_SCALE / grid_size);
    const numCellsY = Math.ceil(canvas.height / MIN_SCALE / grid_size);

    for (let i = 0; i <= numCellsX; i++) {
        const x = i * grid_size;
        backgroundGrid.addWithUpdate(new fabric.Line([x,-grid_size,x,canvas.height / MIN_SCALE], {
            fill: 'black',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            opacity: GRID_OPACITY
        }));
    }

    for (let i = 0; i <= numCellsY; i++) {
        const y = i * grid_size;
        backgroundGrid.addWithUpdate(new fabric.Line([-grid_size,y,canvas.width / MIN_SCALE,y], {
            fill: 'black',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            opacity: GRID_OPACITY
        }));
    }
}
bgGrid();
canvas.add(backgroundGrid);
```

I also found another solution, it is to override the _renderBackground **private** method:

```
const GRID_COLOR = "#000000";
const GRID_OPACITY = 0.3;
const CELL_SIZE = 20;

const MAX_SCALE = 2;
const MIN_SCALE = 0.5;

function snapToGrid(point) {
    return Math.round(point / CELL_SIZE) * CELL_SIZE;
}


var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas', {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
    selectionColor: 'rgba(100,100,100,0.3)', // selection with opacity 0.3
    selectionLineWidth: 2,
    width: window.outerWidth,
    height: window.outerHeight,
    viewportTransform: [1, 0, 0, 1, -window.outerWidth/2, -window.outerHeight/2],
    //stopContextMenu: true, // prevent the right-click context menu from appearing
    fireRightClick: true, // enable firing of right click events
    fireMiddleClick: true, // enable firing of middle click events
});
window.onresize = function() {
    canvas.setWidth(window.outerWidth);
    canvas.setHeight(window.outerHeight);
};

canvas.on("mouse:wheel", function(opt) {
    let zoom = canvas.getZoom();
    zoom *= 0.999 ** opt.e.deltaY;
    if (zoom > MAX_SCALE) zoom = MAX_SCALE;
    if (zoom < MIN_SCALE) zoom = MIN_SCALE;
    
    canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: opt.e.offsetX, y: opt.e.offsetY }, zoom);
    opt.e.preventDefault();
    opt.e.stopPropagation();

});

canvas.on("mouse:up", function(opt) {
    this.setViewportTransform(this.viewportTransform);
    this.isDragging = false;
    this.selection = true;
});

canvas.on("mouse:down", function(opt) {
    if (opt.e.button === 1) {
        this.isDragging = true;
        this.selection = false;
        this.lastPosX = opt.e.clientX;
        this.lastPosY = opt.e.clientY;
    }
});

canvas.on("mouse:move", function(opt) {
    if (this.isDragging) {
        this.viewportTransform[4] += opt.e.clientX - this.lastPosX;
        this.viewportTransform[5] += opt.e.clientY - this.lastPosY;
        
        this.lastPosX = opt.e.clientX;
        this.lastPosY = opt.e.clientY;
        this.requestRenderAll();
    }
});


var rec = new fabric.Rect({
    left: snapToGrid(canvas.width / 2),
    top: snapToGrid(canvas.height / 2),
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    selectable: true,
    evented: true,
    draggable: true,
    angle: 0
  });


rec.on('mousedown', function(options) {
  // Drag start
  console.log('Drag start');
});

rec.on('mouseup', function(options) {
  // Drag end
  console.log('Drag end');
});

rec.on('moving', function(options) {
  // Dragging
  this.left = snapToGrid(this.left);
  this.top = snapToGrid(this.top);
});


canvas._renderBackground = function(ctx) {
    if (!this.backgroundColor) {
        return;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = this.backgroundColor;
    ctx.fillRect(
      0,
      0,
      canvas.width,
      canvas.height
    );

    let zoom = this.getZoom();
    let offsetX = this.viewportTransform[4];
    let offsetY = this.viewportTransform[5];

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#cecece";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  
    gridSize = CELL_SIZE * zoom;
  
    const numCellsX = Math.ceil(canvas.width / gridSize);
    const numCellsY = Math.ceil(canvas.height / gridSize);
              
    gridOffsetX = offsetX % gridSize;
    gridOffsetY = offsetY % gridSize;
  
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();

    for (let i = 0; i <= numCellsX; i++) {
      let x = gridOffsetX + i * gridSize;
      ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
    }
  

    for (let i = 0; i <= numCellsY; i++) {
      let y = gridOffsetY + i * gridSize;
      ctx.moveTo(0, y);
      ctx.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
    }
  
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
}


canvas.add(rec);

canvas.renderAll();
```